# Axion CDM analogous to reheating?

Tags: dark-matter, symmetry-breaking, cosmological-inflation

In a [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0607268v1) on Axions Peccei writes:

> When the Universe goes through the PQ phase transition at $T ∼ f_a >
> > Λ_{QCD}$ the QCD anomaly is ineffective. As a result, early in the
>   Universe $< a_{phys} >$ is arbitrary. Eventually, when the Universe cools
>   down to temperatures of order $T \sim Λ_{QCD}$ the axion obtains a mass and $<a_{phys} >→ 0$. The PQ mechanism through which this happens, however, is
>   not an instantaneous process and $< a_{phys} >$ oscillates to its final
>   value. These coherent $p_a = 0$ axion oscillations contribute to the
>   Universe’s energy density and axions act as cold dark matter.

He denotes by $a$ the axion field and $f_a$ the spontaneous PQ symmetry breaking energy scale.

Does he mean that in the early universe axions would be generated when the PQ symmetry is broken in a process analogous to reheating in inflation, or am I fully mistaken by this analogy?